# Memory copy when casting a list of 2D numpy arrays into a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to cast a list of 2D numpy arrays into a 3D array, and I would like to know whether or not the data is copied.

For example, with this program:

```
images = []
for i in range(10):
    images.append(numpy.random.rand(100, 100))
volume = numpy.array(images)
```

Is there a way to check if `volume[n]` is referring to the same memory block as `images[n]`?

I need my data to be a 3D array, and I'm trying to assess whether I should accept lists of images as an input, or if this will cause data to be copied. Data copy is not acceptable, as I'm working with very large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

I could just reference an question about the storage differences between lists and arrays, but to tailor it your case:

Your list has a data buffer with pointers to the array objects stored elsewhere in memory.  `images.append` just updates that pointer list.  A list copy will just copy the pointers.

An array stores all of its data in a contiguous memory buffer.  So to create `volume` `np.array()` has to copy values from each of the component arrays to its own buffer.  The same applies if some version of `np.concatenate` is used to compile the 3d array.

`numpy` functions often have a `x=np.asarray(x)` statement at the start.  In effect it is saying, "I'm working with an array, but I'll let you give me a list".

You could skip that and accept only a 3d array.  But how was that 3d array constructed?  For a random 3d array you can get by with one statement:

```
arr = numpy.random.rand(10, 100, 100)
```

but if the images are load individually from files, something or someone will have to perform one or more copies to create that 3d array of images.  Will it be you, or your users?

My general advise is don't be too paranoid about making copies - until your code is running and you know, from profiling that the copies are expensive, or you start hitting MemoryError problems.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was really asking, if numpy arrays must necessarily be memory contiguous or if a top level index could reference subarrays that are not contiguous to each other.

Comment: Regarding your questions: I'm working on a generic widget to browse through a stack of images. The images must be provided by users so I'm a bit unsure whether I need to be strict regarding the input data specifications, or try to make users life easier. I'm afraid that some users will request to be able to load data as lists of 2D arrays, or worse, list of lists of lists. And the same users will complain if my widget takes a lot of time re-ordering all that data that was expensive to sort in the first place.

Comment: Btw, my widget needs to be able to transpose the data, to slice the volume orthogonaly to any of the 3 possible directions. That's why I need the data in a numpy array, to use views.
I also plan to accept h5py datasets, which are easier to "transpose" than multi-dimensional lists (https://github.com/PiRK/silx/blob/ImageStack/silx/utils/array_like.py#L211).

I'm expecting data sizes of several gigabytes (possibly hundreds of gigabytes), as my users are scientists working on syncrotron/x-ray imaging techniques.

Answer (score 1):

After importing `numpy`, Windows Task Manager said my Python process used 14 MB. After building `images` (though with `range(5000)`), it was at 396 MB (382 MB more). After building `volume`, it was at 778 MB (another 382 MB more). So looks like it copies. Using NumPy 1.11.1 in Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` allows you to test whether two arrays share memory (which is a decent proxy for weren't copied in this case)

```
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    print(i, numpy.may_share_memory(img, volume))
# all False
```

Looks like they were copied this time.

Answer (score 0):

From [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html?highlight=array):

> **copy : bool**, *optional*
>
> If true (default), then the object is copied. Otherwise, a copy will only be made if `__array__` returns a copy, **if obj is a nested sequence**, or if a copy is needed to satisfy any of the other requirements (dtype, order, etc.).

I'm pretty sure after testing with `copy=False` that you have a nested sequence.  Unfortunately determining if `__array__` returns a copy for a list (or any other iterator) is beyond my google-fu, but it seems likely, as you can't natively iterate a numpy array.